# Windows: interface without ComponentId?

Tags: windows, networking, registry, wireguard

For the application I develop, in C++, I need to get the componentId of an interface. In particular, the WireGuard interface (componentId=wintun that is the adapter installed with the official WireGuard installer). Usually I get it from the registry key,

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-<other_numbers>0318}\<NUMBER>`

where the `<NUMBER>` depends on how many interfaces you have, usually is four digits, like 0015 or 0022...

Inside it, there should be the value "ComponentId", in OpenVPN it should be "tap0901", in WireGuard "wintun".

Sometimes I see that I do not have a ComponentId. I have seen it with WireGuard, but the question is more general:

How can we have an interface without ComponentId? when can it happen? If I don't have the componentId, on which value could I rely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here

[build 10049 breaks openvpn](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web-insiderplat_pc/build-10049-breaks-openvpn-there-are-no-tap/1aea251f-060a-43e9-a488-4ab362b1b30e)

Basically, if you need the "ComponentId" key, check also the "MatchingDeviceId"